# Can't able to bind values to the html table using foreach using knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Hi Iam working for binding list of values using konckout js in api controller here is my code.In knockout iam getting list of values but in view page value is not getting binded.In controller  this is my code

```
 public Qualification Get()
            {
                Qualification qualmodel = new  Qualification();
                Qualify qul = new Qualify();
                qualmodel.leadqualificlist = new List<Qualify>();
                LeadQualificationCriteria leadqual = new LeadQualificationCriteria();
                iWISEDataContainer leadqualif = new iWISEDataContainer();
                foreach (var test in leadqualif.LeadQualificationCriterias)
                {

                    qul.LeadQualifition = test.LeadQualificationFactor;
                    qul.Negativescore = test.NegativeScoreText;
                    qul.Neutralscore = test.PositiveScoreText;
                    qul.Positivescore = test.PositiveScoreText;

                    qualmodel.leadqualificlist.Add(qul);

                }

              return qualmodel;

            }
```

and my Knockout code:

```
function LeadQualificationModel() {
    debugger;
    var self = this;
    self.LeadQualifition = ko.observable("");
    self.Negativescore = ko.observable("");
    self.Neutralscore = ko.observable("");
    self.Positivescore = ko.observable("");
    self.Scoreschk = ko.observable("");
    self.Commenttext = ko.observable("");
    self.leadqualificlist = ko.observableArray();

    var baseUri = '/api/Qualification'; 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Qualification',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data1) {

                self.leadqualificlist(data1.leadqualificlist); //Here iam getting list of values
                debugger;
                //Put the response in ObservableArray                    
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.status + "<--and--> " + error.statusText);
            }
        });    
  $(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    ko.applyBindings(new LeadQualificationModel());
})
```

and my html design

```
<div style="width: 1100px; height: 700px;" class="container">
        <div style="width: 1100px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 400px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood;" align="left">
                        <h3>Qualification Factor</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 400px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood" align="center">
                        <h3>Score</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 400px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood" align="center">
                        <h3>Comment</h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 1100px; height: 580px; border: 1px solid; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;" >    
            <table>              
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: leadqualificlist">                     
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 250px; height: 130px;">                          
                            <h4 data-bind="text: LeadQualifition"></h4>                           
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 580px; height: 80px;">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4>Negative</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4>Neutral</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4>Positive</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">

                                        <h4 data-bind="text: Negativescore">
                                            <br />
                                            0-1-2-3</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4 data-bind="text: Neutralscore">
                                            <br />
                                            4-5-6</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4 data-bind="text: Positivescore">
                                            <br />

                                            7-8-9</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked:$root.Scoreschk" />

                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked: $root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked: $root.Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" data-bind="checked: $root.Scoreschk" />

                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 110px;" data-bind="value:$data.Commenttext">Text Box
                            </textarea>

                        </td>
                    </tr>                                 
                </tbody>  
            </table>

            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="center">

                        @* <button data-bind="click :$root.create"  style="background-color:burlywood">Save</button>*@
                        <input type="submit" title="Save" value="Submit" data-bind="click:$root.create" style="background-color: burlywood" />
                        <input type="submit" title="Save" value="Next Stage" style="background-color: burlywood" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

VIEW MODEL ENTITIES :

```
  public class Qualification 
        {
            public int Qualificationid { get; set; }
            public string LeadQualifition { get; set; }
            public string Negativescore { get; set; }
            public string Neutralscore { get; set; }
            public string Positivescore { get; set; }
            public int Scoreschk { get; set; }
            public string Commenttext { get; set; }

            public List<Qualify> leadqualificlist { get; set; }

        }
```

OTHER ONE :

```
public class Qualify
    {
        public string LeadQualifition { get; set; }
        public string Negativescore { get; set; }
        public string Neutralscore { get; set; }
        public string Positivescore { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT : 
I am getting count as 13 . my Zeroth index values :

```
LeadQualifition = "Winning products and services"
Negativescore = "Competitors very strong in this area"
Neutralscore = "Strong  differentiators"
Positivescore = "Strong differentiators"
```

Likely i am having data for 13 rows .

Please some one suggest to bind values in view page.
Regards,

Comment: the list of data getting from database so i cant use fiddle

Comment: ya but i have seen but did't get error so i think if debug the code than i will be solved

Comment: im getting all the values in self.leadqualificlist(data1.leadqualificlist) but i cant able to bind the calue to view.

Comment: yes i am also getting no error and also no data ? i tried debugging in chrome i can watch the data coming but it is unable to reach view ? Am i missing something in html to get the sent data?

Comment: Do you need to define the `observable` like this `self.leadqualificlist = ko.observableArray([]);`?

Comment: well actually i guess we have to store DATA1 somewhere . so as per knockout i am storing in observable array . i donno it is manditory or not . if i dont store how can i pass data1 (list of values) to VIEW

Answer (score 0):

i think u have to push data in observable array like

```
for(  i=0; i<=data1.length;i++)

  self.leadqualificlist.Push(data1[i]) /// plz modify as per your data

}
```

Comment: TY for responding . The above mentioned for loop is not even entering . any suggestions mate

Comment: public List<Qualify> leadqualificlist { get; set; } is my viewmodel entity / is this what you need ?

Comment: edited my post my viewe model entity classes added . check it

Comment: i tired giving data1.length = 12 static .Later inside the loop I AM GETTING :
 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'Push' . 

Am i missig something ? any scripting issue acc to you ?

Comment: please debug the code and in success function put break point if u found the data copy the data and send me please

Comment: added as edit in the post . please check it . anything need let me know

Comment: plz check i have tried something for u i thin it will help u  
http://jsfiddle.net/AGp5A/1/

Comment: your efforts are appreciated ty so much but it didnt work for me sadly , same issue in for loop 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference

Comment: first try to push 2 or 3 data from response and check it works or not

Answer (score 0):

I do it using the following;

A local function defined in the view model to support the array membership type, e.g.

```
var Device = function (data) {
    this.id= ko.protectedObservable(data.id);
    this.name= ko.protectedObservable(data.name);
};
```

If the ajax response is successful I map the result, e.g. in the following example `devices` is the observable array.

```
success: function (data) {
    var mappedDevices = $.map(data.devices, function (item) { return new Device(item); });

    self.devices(mappedDevices);
    // Update the gui
    self.devicesLoaded(true);
    $('#devices-table').trigger('update');
}
```

If the example provided by Vivek isn't working, use the browser's dev tools to check the response does actually have data in the `leadqualificlist` array.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AaronMorganNZ/hJ65K/) example.

Comment: well mate i am brand new to Knockout i am not sure what you are refering . would please be more eloborate . i am editing my post , plase find the viewmodel entities